# Accessing non-axis data attributes in dimple.js

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

One of my favorite aspects of d3 is that it groups collections of data that can be accessed easily at any point in the process of creating and drawing a visualization.

I picked up Dimple to build some prettier graphs, implementing the following example:
http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_dynamic_line_color

I'd like to access an ID attribute of my data in an onclick event associated with the data points. Unfortunately, the only data passed to these events by dimple is the axis coordinates.

Is there a simple way to get at the rest of the attributes of the data in dimple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that dimple will pre-aggregate the data so it doesn't work from the original data rows.  Virtually all of the examples on the dimple website are drawn from the same tsv and in each case dimple aggregates the data to different levels.  The benefit of this is that it means you can use very similar code for a line, area, bubble, bar or pie chart at any level of aggregation without any data manipulation in your own code.

Therefore if you would like another field it must be part of the aggregation, you can include as many fields as you like in the the series definition so:

```
  var lines = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
```

could become:

```
  var lines = myChart.addSeries(["Brand", "Owner", "SKU", "Product"], dimple.plot.line);
```

And those 4 fields would be accessible.

Beware though that a line will be drawn for every distinct combination of those dimension values so you can't use this method to access a more granular datum.

Comment: Thanks, that about sums it up. Even though it does make things simpler and cleaner I wish that I could attach metadata to my chart's data points in a simpler way.

Comment: if you could provide an example or reproducible data, I'm sure dimple's flexibility would allow us to accomplish your objective; just let us know

Comment: It would probably be possible to include an array of source rows in every data row after aggregation. Please create an issue in GitHub if this is something you would be interested in seeing in the library

Comment: I find it useful, and have created an issue here https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/issues/236, and a Pull Request with a possible implementation (https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/pull/237)